# Displaying item hierarchy using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a object hierarchy created from a class like this:

```
public class MyTreeItem
{
    public MyTreeItem Parent{get;set}
    public IList<MyTreeItem> Children{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
    //Other properties.
}
```

Suppose I have an object tree of `MyTreeItem`s such as the following:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 /\    \
D  E    F
```

Within my program, I will acquire some object in the above hierarchy from a DB query. This item will belong to the second or third level of the tree (`B, C, D, E or F` in this case). I want to display the full tree path of the acquired object using the `Parent` property (Kind of like how the path is shown in Windows Explorer.). Suppose I selected the item `B`, then the path should be displayed as `A -> B`. If I selected `E`, the path should be `A -> B -> E`. Is there a way to get this done in XAML?

Comment: How do you want to display it? as a string showing the path or as a treeview?

Comment: Preferably as a string. But even a `TreeView` would be ok if the former is not possible. I thought I could get this done with a `TextBlock` by using `MultiBinding`, but I can't get my head around how to handle two different depths of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you are wanting to show this as a string, then all you need to do is design a property that returns the breadcrumb trail based on the parent...

Note: This assumes the 'A' and 'B' are the `Description` property...

```
public string Breadcrumb
{
    get
    {
        string breadcrumb = Description;

        if(Parent === null)
            return breadcrumb;

        for(MyTreeItem currentItem = Parent; currentItem != null ; currentItem = currentItem.Parent)
        {
            breadcrumb = string.Format("{0) -> {1}", currentItem.Description, breadcrumb);
        }

        return breadcrumb;
    }
}
```

basically the logic is to keep adding the parent's descirption (formatted with the `->`) on the front of the current breadcrumb, the `for` loop will then set the currentItem to the `Parent` (which should be null at the top level)

e.g for Node E it will build the breadcrumb as such:

> Loop 0: E
>   Loop 1: B -> E
>   Loop 2: A -> B -> E

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know if this can be done without resorting to code-behind and purely in XAML. See my question.

Comment: I'm going to say you probably can't. If you want to show it using a treeview then use the `TreeView` control and the `HierachicalDataTemplate`, but apart from that, i don't think that it is possible in XAML

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `IValueConverter` and bind it to the `TextBlock` text DP.

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      string hierarchy = String.Empty;
      if(value != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
      {
         MyTreeItem item = value;
         hierarchy = value.Description;
         MyTreeItem parentItem = item.Parent;
         while(parentItem != null)
         {
            hierarchy = string.Format("{0) -> {1}", parentItem.Description, 
                                                       hierarchy);
            parentItem = parentItem.Parent;
         }
      }
      return hierarchy;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Here goes your XAML -

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem,
                          Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```